# Expo Background Permissions Async is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, permissions, background, expo

I am developing an app where my users will sometimes need to be tracked as they are outside of the app. I have gone through the expo docs and it appears I am supposed to work with Foreground and Background Permissions Async functions but my expo app does not recognize either version. Has anyone else encountered this? How do I fix this? Below is some of my code:

```
import * as  Permissions from 'expo-permissions'; 
import * as Request from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'


useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect (() =>{
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice){
        setErrorMsg2(
          'Whoops'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status2 } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status2 !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg2('Permission to access background location was denied');
        return;
      }
      let location2 = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})
      setLocation2(location2)
    })()
  },[])

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  }
   else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  let text2 = 'Also Wating...';
    if (errorMsg2){
      text2 = errorMsg2;
    }
    else if (location) {
      text2 = JSON.stringify(location)
    }
```

I am running Expo in managed workflow, currently using Expo version 3.23.2, but have also tested it on version 4.3.2, and have been thrown the same errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While using `expo-location`, you have to keep these points in mind :

1. `Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync()` **Asks the user to grant permissions for location while the app is in the background. On Android 11 or higher: this method will open the system settings page - before that happens you should explain to the user why your application needs background location permission**.
2. **Foreground permissions should be granted before asking for the background permissions (your app can't obtain background permission without foreground permission)**.

Refer to the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationrequestbackgroundpermissionsasync)

**Note : This has been tested on SDK 41 and `expo-location`'s version `12.2.1`**

[Working Example for Background Location here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/backgroundlocation)

How I've implemented it

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);

      let backPerm = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      console.log(backPerm);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = "Waiting..";
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

First, it asks me the foreground Permission, I tapped on `While Using the app`

[image: Foregorund Permission Prompt]

Then, for background location permission it takes me to the device settings page to allow location access in the background

[image: Background Location Permission Settings Page]

If by any chance this doesn't work as expected, try these steps

1. Clear all the permission given to `Expo Go` app.
2. Clear Cache and app data
3. Uninstall and restart your device, and then again download `Expo go` app

Comment: I keep getting the same error: "Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync is not a function." Any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: Make sure your import statement is correct. Like this, `import * as Location from 'expo-location';` and not like this, `import { Location } from "expo-location"`. Also, is the snack that I provided working perfectly on your device?

Comment: No, that's how I have it, It still throws an error. Does it have anything to do with my version of Expo?

Comment: Yeah, I think the same. The snack that I provided is working on Expo SDK 41. Not checked on SDK 42.

Comment: I am currently running Expo 3.23.2, so while I don't know my SDK offhand (I think it's 40) I definitely don't have the newest lol

Comment: And what is the version of `expo-location` that you use? The snack that I provided uses `12.0.4`

Comment: The one that I was using was only using 10.0, but I had thought ahead and upgraded to 12.0.4. I thought it might still work (since expo allows that sometimes) but this could be the root cause, unless you have any other suggestions

Comment: I am running on Expo SDK 40.0. I tested this on SDK 41 and it did work like it was supposed to. I would recommend making an edit above noting that this is good for Expo SDK 41 and expo-location version 12.2.1 (or whatever the most recent version as of July 6 2021.) Thank you for the assistance

Comment: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: One of the `NSLocation*UsageDescription` keys must be present in Info.plist to be able to use geolocation.]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:106:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules/expo-location/build/Location.js:228:17 in requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync
at node_modules/expo-location/build/Location.js:227:7 in requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync
at App.js:20:27 in <anonymous>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of task runner from expo, I use notifee for dedicated foreground service to have more granular control. Then I simply create a simple function with setTimeout to run things periodically and use expo-location to grab the location.

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { startActivityAsync, ActivityAction } from 'expo-intent-launcher';
import notifee, { type Event, AndroidColor, EventType } from '@notifee/react-native';
import type { LocationObject } from 'expo-location';

export { register, unregister }

async function waitUntil(
  conditionPromise: () => Promise<boolean>,
  loopFunc: () => Promise<any>,
  timeout: number
) {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`Creating interval task at date: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);

    const interval = setInterval(
      async () => {
        const condition = await conditionPromise();
        if (condition) {
          console.log(`Stopping interval task at date: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
          resolve('stopping');
          clearInterval(interval);
          return;
        } else {
          return loopFunc();
        }
      },
      timeout
    );
  });
}

async function register(func: (locations: LocationObject[]) => Promise<void>) {
  // Request permissions (required for iOS)
  await notifee.requestPermission()

  // Create a channel (required for Android)
  const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
    id: 'default',
    name: 'Default Channel',
  });

  notifee.registerForegroundService((notification) => {
    console.log('register foreground', notification);
    return new Promise(() => {
      waitUntil(async () => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Notification_id');
        //console.log(`AsyncStorage @Notification_id: ${value}`);
        return !value;
      }, async () => {
        let locationObject;

        try {
          locationObject = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
          });
          //console.log(`Got background fetch call at date: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);

          const prevLocations = JSON.parse((await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Locations')) || '[]') as LocationObject[];
          const locations = [...prevLocations, locationObject]

          await func(locations); // callback to application layer

          // cleanup
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@Locations');

          // update our live status of notification to indicate it is working
          const notificationId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Notification_id');
          if (notificationId) {
            await notifee.displayNotification({
              id: notificationId,
              title: notification.title,
              body: notification.body,
              android: {
                ...notification.android,
                color: AndroidColor.NAVY,
                ongoing: true,
                progress: {
                  indeterminate: true,
                },
                pressAction: {
                  id: 'stop',
                },
              },
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          //console.log('Inside try catch', e);
          if (e instanceof Error) {
            const notificationId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Notification_id');
            // update our foreground notification to indicate error
            if (notificationId) {
              await notifee.displayNotification({
                id: notificationId,
                title: notification.title,
                body: e.message,
                android: {
                  ...notification.android,
                  color: AndroidColor.OLIVE,
                  ongoing: true,
                  progress: undefined,
                  pressAction: {
                    id: 'error',
                  },
                }
              });
            }

            if (/network request failed/i.test(e.message)) {
              // save
              await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Locations', JSON.stringify(locations));
            }
          }
        }
      }, 30000).catch(console.log)

      const eventCallback = async ({ type, detail }: Event) => {
        if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS || type === EventType.PRESS) {
          if (detail?.pressAction?.id === 'stop') {
            await notifee.stopForegroundService();
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@Notification_id');
          } else if (detail?.pressAction?.id === 'error') {
            // Go to location sources settings page, regardless of error
            await startActivityAsync(ActivityAction.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
          }
        }
      }

      notifee.onForegroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
        //console.log(`onForegroundEvent`, type, JSON.stringify(detail, null, 4));
        await eventCallback({ type, detail }).catch(console.log);
      });

      notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
        //console.log(`onBackgroundEvent`, type, JSON.stringify(detail, null, 4));
        await eventCallback({ type, detail });
      });
    });
  });

  const notificationId = await notifee.displayNotification({
    title: 'App',
    body: 'Tracking your location in the background. Click notification to disable.',
    android: {
      channelId,
      asForegroundService: true,
      color: AndroidColor.NAVY,
      ongoing: true,
      colorized: true,
      pressAction: {
        id: 'stop',
      },
    },
  });

  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Notification_id', notificationId)

  console.log(`Registered notification at date: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);

  return notificationId;
}

async function unregister(notificationId?: string) {
  await notifee.stopForegroundService();
  notificationId && await notifee.cancelNotification(notificationId);

  await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@Notification_id');

  console.log(`Unregister notification at date: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
}
```